# OnItemSelectedListener for Spinner in Android development

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I'm using a spinner in order to select a certain value, and in the activity that contains the spinnr, I've implemented OnItemSelectedListener.

in the OnCreate() method, I've defined:
`spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);`

but it doesn't get to the method onItemSelected(), my guess is that I'm not sending the right variable ("this").

what should I send to setOnItemSelectedListener in order for this to get to the method?
Thank You!

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If not add relevant code to your post. It'll help identify your issues.

Answer (score 1):

> activity that contains the spinnr, I've implemented
>   OnItemSelectedListener

If `OnItemSelectedListener` listener is implemented in Activity then override `onItemSelected` in Activity :

```
  @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here
    }
```

Comment: I've done that, but my question is which veriable am i supposed to send to 'spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener'?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                   int arg2, long arg3) {
            //Do something

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Also you can look at this. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Comment: I have several spinners with kind of identical actions that follows the ItemSelected - This way (with new adapterView...) did work, but I want to do the action using the OnItemSelectedListener interface